# flutter how to support multiple screen sizes analog to android sdp

Tags: android, flutter, sdp

I know that in android to support multiple screen size we have **sdp**.

Whats is equivalent in flutter? what is best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is the using of [screen utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

Using this package you can set initial  size which designer designed.

For example: 
**If the design is based on the size of the iPhone6 ​​(iPhone6 ​​750*1334)**

```
ScreenUtil.init(context, width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: false);
```

And if the designer set the size of box 375x200

Then you can set the sizes using following example code :

```
Container(

            width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(375),
            height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(200),

         )
```